# how to print tail of path filename using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I've searched it with no success.

I have a file with pathes.
I want to print the tail of a all pathes.
for example (for every line in file):

```
/homes/work/abc.txt
--> abc.txt
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What would you want to happen if your file contained `/usr/bin/`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' input.txt
```

will give output of:

```
abc1.txt
abc2.txt
abc3.txt
```

for:

```
$>cat input.txt
text path/to/file/abc1.txt
path/to/file/abc2.txt
path/to/file/abc3.txt
```

Comment: Can be shorten some `awk -F/ '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @Jotne: or `awk -F/ '$0=$NF'`

Comment: @Thor Very nice indeed

Comment: I second that! Nice to know

Comment: Thanks!
what $NF stand for?

Comment: this is an old post... but I was wondering, too... [what does $NF stand for?](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-17)  apparently, it is the number fields variable.

Comment: @Thor This `awk -F/ '$0=$NF'` will fail for value `0`, so it need to be `awk -F/ '{$0=$NF}1'` (see my updated post)

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: `NF` is the number of fields, so `$NF` refers to the last field. @jotne: This is true for this rare case and indeed the safer way to go.

Answer (score 5):

How about this `awk`

```
echo "/homes/work/abc.txt" | awk '{sub(/.*\//,x)}1'
abc.txt
```

Since `.*` is greedy, it will continue until last `/`
So here we remove all until last `/` with `x`, and since `x` is empty, gives nothing.

---

Thors version

```
echo "/homes/work/abc.txt" | awk -F/ '$0=$NF'
abc.txt
```

NB this will fail for `/homes/work/0` or `0,0` etc so better use:

```
echo "/homes/work/abc.txt" | awk -F/ '{$0=$NF}1'
```

Answer (score 4):

`awk` solutions are already provided by *@Jotne* and *@bashophil*

Here are some other variations *(just for fun)*

---

Using `sed`

```
sed 's:.*/::' file
```

---

Using `grep`

```
grep -oP '(.*/)?\K.*' file
```

---

Using `cut` - added by *@Thor*

```
rev file | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

---

Using `basename` - suggested by *@fedorqui* and *@EdMorton*

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  basename "$line" 
done < file
```

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for your suggestion! Added to solution.

Comment: Note in my proposed version it won't fail if file paths have white spaces, because quoting the variable when calling `basename` avoids it.

Comment: @fedorqui that's cool. actually i had tried the same earlier but might have missed quotes so decided to go with `xargs` as produced results were same. Now I have removed that bad practice. This is *fun*. Thanks :)

Comment: The loop will fail if your file names contain backslashes or can start with white space. Always us `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a very specific reason not to. Obviously, the approach just won't work at all if the file names contain newlines but that's a whole other can of worms.